# Breadth-First Search implementation not Working

Tags: java

I have a problem with the implementation of the breadth-first search algorithm, I have a method that gives me an array of integers from 0-8, in random order. I also have an integer m that tells me which number is blank. Here are the rules:

I get a block of numbers, like:

```
456           
782        
301
```

And lets say that 8 is the blank value, I can swap it with 5, 7, 2, and 0. since they are directly next to it. I have to use breadth-first search to solve this puzzle. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Solution {

    /******************************************
     * Implementation Here
     ***************************************/

    /*
     * Implementation here: you need to implement the Breadth First Search
     * Method
     */
    /* Please refer the instruction document for this function in details */

    public static LinkedHashSet<int[]> OPEN = new LinkedHashSet<int[]>();
        public static HashSet<int[]> CLOSED = new HashSet<int[]>();
    public static boolean STATE = false;
    public static int empty;

    public static void breadthFirstSearch(int[] num, int m, Vector solution1) {
        int statesVisited = 0;
        for(int i : num) {
            if(num[i] == m) {
                empty = i;
            }
        }

        int[] start = num;
        int[] goal = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        int[] X;
        int[] temp = {};

        OPEN.add(start);

        while (OPEN.isEmpty() == false && STATE == false) {

            X = OPEN.iterator().next();
            OPEN.remove(X);

            int pos = empty; // get position of ZERO or EMPTY SPACE
            if (compareArray(X,goal)) {
                System.out.println("SUCCESS");

                STATE = true;
            } else {
                // generate child nodes
                CLOSED.add(X);

                temp = up(X, pos);
                if (temp != null)
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                temp = left(X, pos);
                if (temp != null)
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                temp = down(X, pos);
                if (temp != null)
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                temp = right(X, pos);
                if (temp != null)
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                if(OPEN.isEmpty()) 
                    System.out.println("Ending loop");
            }
        }

    }
    public static boolean compareArray(int[] a, int[] b) {
        for(int i: a) 
            if(a[i] != b[i])
                return false;

        return true;

    }

    public static int[] up(int[] s, int p) {
        int[] str = s;
        if (p > 3) {
            int temp = str[p-3];
            str[p-3] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;


        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return null;
    }


    public static int[] down(int[] s, int p) {
        int[] str = s;
        if (p < 6) {
            int temp = str[p+3];
            str[p+3] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;

        }

        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return null;
    }


    public static int[] left(int[] s, int p) {
        int[] str = s;
        if (p != 0 && p != 3 && p != 6) {
            int temp = str[p-1];
            str[p-1] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;

        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return null;
    }


    public static int[] right(int[] s, int p) {
        int[] str = s;
        if (p != 2 && p != 5 && p != 8) {
            int temp = str[p+1];
            str[p+1] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false)
            return str;
        else
            return null;
    }
    public static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, 3));
        System.out.println(s.substring(3, 6));
        System.out.println(s.substring(6, 9));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This code just immediately ends, and never finds an answer. Perhaps I have done something wrong? Please help.

Please Note: This is my first question on StackOverFlow, so if anyone has any criticisms please tell me and I will fix them right away.

Comment: can you give us the expected output after you run your program on the given example? are you just supposed to output the values that are next to the given blank value?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz no it's supposed to sort it so output 012345678

Comment: Ohh I get it, looks like it is a puzzle game where you are given a 2D board with numbers and a blank space. You can swap the numbers only to blank space as the movable piece can move only to the blank space if adjacent. So you have to minimize distance from their original position, using BFS to get it arranged in order, am I right? Are you trying something like this?

Comment: @Suparshva yes, exactly!

Comment: You will have to calculate position of empty cell every-time as you will have a different board every-time. Here in code you are calculating only once and using it every-time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a parameter which isn't doing anything, `Vector solution` in:

```
public static void breadthFirstSearch(int[] num, int m, Vector solution1)
```

Also you are passing in the position of the zero element which you are representing as m, then assigning a local variable to that position, seems a little pointless to me there's no need to pass in the zero position if you're going to search for it anyway.

Updated breadth first search method:

```
public static void breadthFirstSearch(int[] num) {
    for (int i : num) {
        if (num[i] == 0) {
            empty = i;
        }
    }

    int[] start = num;
    int[] goal = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0};
    int[] X;
    int[] temp = {};

    OPEN.add(start);

    while (OPEN.isEmpty() == false && STATE == false) {

        X = OPEN.iterator().next();
        OPEN.remove(X);
        int pos = empty; // get position of ZERO or EMPTY SPACE
        if (Arrays.equals(X, goal)) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
            STATE = true;
        } else {
            // generate child nodes
            CLOSED.add(X);
            temp = up(X, pos);
            if (temp != null) {
                OPEN.add(temp);
            }
            temp = left(X, pos);
            if (temp != null) {
                OPEN.add(temp);
            }
            temp = down(X, pos);
            if (temp != null) {
                OPEN.add(temp);
            }
            temp = right(X, pos);
            if (temp != null) {
                OPEN.add(temp);
            }
            if (OPEN.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Ending loop");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **main** issue with your program was that within your movement methods `up()`, `down()`, `left()`, `right()`. You weren't creating complete copies of the arrays, thus resulting in modifications happening to the original array.

Thus this assignment:
`int[] str = s;`

must be changed to:

```
   int[] str = new int[s.length];
   System.arraycopy(s, 0, str, 0, s.length);
```

Here's an example of a completed method:

```
public static int[] up(int[] s, int p) {
    int[] str = new int[s.length];
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, str, 0, s.length);

    if (p > 3) {
        int temp = str[p - 3];
        str[p - 3] = str[p];
        str[p] = temp;
    }
    // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
    if (!OPEN.contains(str) && !CLOSED.contains(str)) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SIDE NOTE** (Not essential):

There are certain permutations of the array which won't result in the goal state. This puzzle itself can have a total number of `9!` configurations, but actually only `9!/2` of these are solvable.

I wrote an algorithm for checking the [parity](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m308-02b/projects/grant/fifteen.html) of the puzzle, which can be done as a kind of preprocessing, I used it in order to create random instances for testing the data.

```
public  boolean isSolvable(int[] puzzle) {
    boolean parity = true;
    int gridWidth = (int) Math.sqrt(puzzle.length);
    boolean blankRowEven = true; // the row with the blank tile

    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
        if (puzzle[i] == 0) { // the blank tile
            blankRowEven = (i / gridWidth) % 2==0;
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < puzzle.length; j++) {
            if (puzzle[i] > puzzle[j] && puzzle[j] != 0) {
                parity = !parity;
            }
        }
    }

    // even grid with blank on even row; counting from top
    if (gridWidth % 2 == 0 && blankRowEven) { 
        return !parity;
    }
    return parity;
}
```

**For the vector**

You want to be able to print out the path that has been taken to get to the goal state, I would recommend having a class for the `State` such:

```
private State previousState;
private int[] current;

public State(int[] current, State previousState) {
    this.current = current;
    this.previousState = previousState
}

public State getPreviouState(){
    return previousState;
}
public int[] getCurrentState(){
    return currentState;
}
```

Then when you have the goal `State` you can loop through all the previous States to see the path it took.

```
State current = GOAL;
while(current != null){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(current));
    current = current.getPreviousState();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! It really helped! My question is, now I have to implement the Vector solution in such a way that it has the correct places that the blank space is supposed to be. How could I do that? I've been thinking about this for hours, and I can't think of a way to do that.

Comment: What do you mean where the blank space is supposed to be? do you mean each iteration add the blank space position to a vector? @KaterinaChernykh What use will this vector be?

Comment: In the breadthFirstSearch method, there was originally a solution vector that was passed in. This vector should contain the correct path the blank tile should take to solve the puzzle. So yeah where the blank tile should be at each iteration.

Comment: I understand, in order to do this you will need to create a class. In this class it will contain attributes such as the current state and the previous state, I will edit the code and show you what I mean @KaterinaChernykh

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I spent like 3 hours trying to figure out how to do that, with no luck. Again, thanks.

Comment: @Fubar the last part is not clear to me can you elaborate more I find the goal state  but not getting the right path so how we can get the right path in order to reach in the final goal like if we have this array num[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,8,6,7} where the blank tile is 8 at index 6. by solving this array in paper the right path is = {7, 8} so how we can get this path by swapping the each tiles up,down,left and right. need your help. thanks

Comment: So when you choose a move, you should create a new State object, `State s = new State(previousState,currentState)` @KaterinaChernykh also to get my attention, you need to write @Fubar else I don't get a notification

Answer (score 1):

The method up(...) has an error:

You have:

```
 str[p] = str[p-3];
```

Which I'm guessing should be:

```
 str[p] = temp;
```

Comment: Fixed it, still no luck, but thatnks for the tip :)