# Breadth-First Search 8 Tile Game

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I created a breadth-first-search based 8 tile game. let me explain the game:

You are given an array of 8 integers:

```
012
348
675
```

And are given an Integer m, which tells you which tile is blank, in this example lets say it will be 8. You can only swap this tile with tiles directly above, below to the right to left of it, using this method you need to sort the array, like so:

```
012
345
678
```

And you need to put the steps your blank space has taken into a vector. So in the above example the vector would be 5,8 because the blank space started at pos#5 and ended at pos#8 when it was sorted. I created the code for sorting, now I can't figure out how to add the positions into the vector, here is my code:

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Solution {

    /******************************************
     * Implementation Here
     ***************************************/

    /*
     * Implementation here: you need to implement the Breadth First Search
     * Method
     */
    /* Please refer the instruction document for this function in details */

    public static LinkedHashSet<int[]> OPEN = new LinkedHashSet<int[]>();
    public static HashSet<int[]> CLOSED = new HashSet<int[]>();
    public static boolean STATE = false;
    public static int empty;

    public static void breadthFirstSearch(int[] num, int m, Vector solution1) {

        //int[] start = num;
        int[] start = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7};
        m = 7;
        int[] goal = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        int[] X;
        int[] temp = {};

        OPEN.add(start);

        while (OPEN.isEmpty() == false) {


            X = OPEN.iterator().next();
            OPEN.remove(X);

            for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
                if (X[i] == m) {
                    empty = i;
                    System.out.println("empty = " + empty);
                    solution1.addElement(empty);
                }
            }

            // get position of ZERO or EMPTY SPACE
            if (compareArray(X, goal)) {


                System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                for(Object i : solution1) {
                    System.out.println((int)i);
                }
                print(X);
                break;
            } else {


                //print(X);
                System.out.println("------");

                // generate child nodes
                CLOSED.add(X);
                int[][] y = new int[4][9];
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 9; i1++)
                        y[i][i1] = X[i1];

                temp = up(y[0], empty);
                if (temp != null) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    System.out.println("doing up");

                    System.out.println("added "+ empty);
                //  print(temp);

                }

                temp = left(y[1], empty);

                if (temp != null) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    System.out.println("doing left");

                    System.out.println("added "+ empty);
            //      print(temp);
                }

                temp = down(y[2], empty);
                if (temp != null) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    System.out.println("doing down");

                    System.out.println("added "+ empty);
            //      print(temp);
                }
                temp = right(y[3], empty);
                if (temp != null) {
                    OPEN.add(temp);
                    System.out.println("doing right");

                    System.out.println("added "+ empty);
            //      print(temp);

                }
                if (OPEN.isEmpty()) {
                    // System.out.println("Ending loop");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void print(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println(arr[0] + " " + arr[1] + " " + arr[2]);
        System.out.println(arr[3] + " " + arr[4] + " " + arr[5]);
        System.out.println(arr[6] + " " + arr[7] + " " + arr[8]);
        System.out.println("---------");

    }

    public static boolean compareArray(int[] a, int[] b) {

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] != i)
                return false;

        return true;

    }

    public static int[] up(int[] s, int p) {
        boolean b = false;
        int[] str = s;
        if (p > 3) {
            int temp = str[p - 3];
            str[p - 3] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;
            b = true;

        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        int[] t = new int[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            t[i] = str[i];

        if (!OPEN.contains(t) && CLOSED.contains(t) == false && b)
            return str;
        else {
            System.out.println("returning null for up");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static int[] down(int[] s, int p) {

        int[] str = s;
        boolean b = false;
        if (p < 6) {
            int temp = str[p + 3];
            str[p + 3] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;

            b = true;
        }
        int[] t = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            t[i] = str[i];

        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false && (b))
            return str;
        else {
            System.out.println("returning null for down");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static int[] left(int[] s, int p) {
        int[] str = s;
        boolean b = false;
        if (p != 0 && p != 3 && p != 6) {
            int temp = str[p - 1];
            str[p - 1] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;
            b = true;
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        int[] t = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            t[i] = str[i];

        if (!OPEN.contains(str) && CLOSED.contains(str) == false && (b))
            return str;
        else {
            System.out.println("returning null for left");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static int[] right(int[] s, int p) {
        boolean b = false;
        int[] str = s;
        if (p != 2 && p != 5 && p != 8) {
            int temp = str[p + 1];
            str[p + 1] = str[p];
            str[p] = temp;
            b = true;
        }
        // Eliminates child of X if its on OPEN or CLOSED
        int[] t = new int[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            t[i] = str[i];

        if (!OPEN.contains(t) && CLOSED.contains(t) == false && (b))
            return str;
        else {
            System.out.println("returning null for right");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't understand what I'm talking about look here:

https://jackcanty.com/solving-8-puzzle-with-artificial-intelligence.html

Answer (score 0):

This code is exactly the same as one that I recently answered, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684745/breadth-first-search-implementation-not-working/43688780#43688780) and update your code accordingly.

Comment: hah! thats actually someone from my class! We had the same homework assignment!

Comment: let me know if it helped you @arsen